# Can someone show me HOW to do this, I don't just want the answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$4n$ to the power of $3$ over $2 = 8$ to the power of negative $1$ over $3$

Written Differently for Clarity:

$$(4n)^\frac{3}{2} = (8)^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$

---

> **EDIT**
>
> Actually, the problem should be solving $4n^{\frac{3}{2}} = 8^{-\frac{1}{3}}$.  Another user edited this question for clarity, but they edited it incorrectly to add parentheses around the right hand side, as can be seen above.

Comment: Start using $8=2^3$

Comment: Or you can start by raising both sides to the $\frac{2}{3}$ power.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @user261310 What do you mean with "show"? The equation is *solved* for $n$ with applications of the field axioms. But I'm not sure if what you want is a deep explanation.

Comment: @user261310 If the edit is wrong, you can simply edit it again.

Comment: Ok, I answered on the first question. and after posting the answer I found the question was wrongly edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$4n^{\frac32} = 8^{-\frac{1}{3}}= \frac{1}{8^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
$$4\sqrt{n^3}= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{8}}= \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\sqrt{n^3}= \frac{1}{8}$$
$$\left(\sqrt{n^3}\right)^2= \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2$$
$$\left|n^3\right|= \frac{1}{8^2}=\frac{1}{64}$$
Note that $n^{\frac32}$ or $\sqrt{n^3}$ implies that $n^3\geq 0$ and we can drop the absolute value bars. So now we have
$$n^3=\frac{1}{64}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{n^3}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{64}}$$
$$n=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{64}}=\frac14$$

Answer (score 1):

$4n^{\frac{3}{2}}=8^{-\frac{1}{3}} \iff 4n^{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{1}{2} \iff n^{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{1}{8} \iff n^3=\frac{1}{64} \iff n= \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: How did you get to 8n^3/2? Also the answer should be 1/4

Comment: The answer is surely not 1/4. (4)^(3/2)=8

Comment: I'm afraid it is

Comment: @user261310 Where did you get that answer from?  I think it's wrong.

Comment: @user261310: I'm afraid it isn't. If you substitute $n=\frac 14$ in your original equation, the left hand side is $1$ and the right hand side is $\frac 12$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the official edexcel revision guide isn't wrong :/

Comment: (no offence) but there are plenty of different answers provided by users here. Also the guide has made it the last question and has put colours around it (sounds silly I know) to make a thing of it being the last question so it's probably the least likely question they would make a mistake on.

Comment: @user261310 Take it from me.  I've seen plenty of mistakes in official solution manuals.  Also, when I was teaching precalculus earlier, I was reviewing the notes of a section of the book before I was about to lecture on them, and I found an error in one of the examples that they work through!  It was a blatant and confusing error.  So the official document you are using is wrong about this answer.

Comment: @user261310 Also, all of the answers posted on here are correct.  They might look different, but they aren't, just like $2^{2}$ looks different from $4$, but it equals $4$.

Comment: Would the answer be any different without the brackets?

Comment: @user261310 What do you mean?  Do you mean solving $4n^{\frac{3}{2}} = 8^{-\frac{1}{3}}$? If so, yes the answer would be very different.

Comment: Oh, because that is the actual question. Someone edited it and added brackets

Comment: @user261310 Ok, well then that is the problem.  Let me edit my answer (which is not the current answer we are talking about) to show you how to solve the right problem.

Comment: Well if it is $4n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Can someone show me how to solve it correctly now please :)

Comment: Already corrected my answer. Check it.

Comment: Thank you, my dilemma was I didn't know you could divide 4n^3/2 by 4

Answer (score 1):

$${ \left( 4n \right)  }^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  }={ \left( 8 \right)  }^{ -\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }\\ \left( { \left( 4n \right)  }^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } \right) ^{ 2/3 }=\left( { \left( { 2 }^{ 3 } \right)  }^{ -\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  } \right) ^{ 2/3 }\\ 4n=2^{ -\frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }\\ n=\frac { 2^{ -\frac { 2 }{ 3 }  } }{ 4 } =\frac { 1 }{ 4\sqrt [ 3 ]{ 4 }  } $$

Comment: Dear downvoter, can you explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: Turns out that wasn't actually the question (I'm not the downvoter btw)

Answer (score 0):

We have that $4n^{3/2}=8^{-1/3}$. Proceed as follows, to find $n$.

- Simplify $8^{-1/3}=1/\sqrt[3]{8}=1/2$
- Divide both sides by 4 to get $n^{3/2}=1/8$. This is the next step, bearing in mind the order of operations, which is often remembered with the phrase BODMAS(/BIDMAS) (Brackets, Other(/Indices), Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction). That is, if we were to add in unnecessary brackets to emphasize the order, we would write $4(n^{3/2})=1/2$, and we can see dividing by 4 is the next available choice to isolate $n$.
- Raise both sides to the power 2/3 (or if you like, take the "3/2"th root) of both sides, and simplify, to get $n=(1/8)^{2/3}=1/8^{2/3}=1/\sqrt[3]{8}^2=1/2^2=1/4$

Answer (score 0):

So the real problem we are trying to complete is to solve $4n^{\frac{3}{2}} = 8^{-\frac{1}{3}}$.

The way to do this is to first divide both sides by $4$ and get:

$n^{\frac{3}{2}} = \dfrac{8^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{4}$

Now, since $8 = 2^{3}$ and $4 = 2^{2}$, we can rewrite this as:

$n^{\frac{3}{2}} = \dfrac{(2^{3})^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{2^{2}}$

and in the numerator, since we have something with a power raised to another power, we can multiply the two powers to get:

$n^{\frac{3}{2}} = \dfrac{2^{3(-\frac{1}{3})}}{2^{2}}$

which gives

$n^{\frac{3}{2}} = \dfrac{2^{-1}}{2^{2}}$

Now, raising something to a negative exponent means you move it through the fraction either up or down depending on where it started.  So since $2^{-1}$ is in the numerator, we move it down to the denominator and remove the negative in the exponent, to get:

$n^{\frac{3}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{2^{1}2^{2}}$

Since we are multiplying two things raised to exponents with the same base in the denominator (the base is $2$), we can just add the exponents to get:

$n^{\frac{3}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{2^{3}}$

Finally, we can raise both sides to the $\frac{2}{3}$ power to get:

$(n^{\frac{3}{2}})^{\frac{2}{3}} = \left (\dfrac{1}{2^{3}} \right )^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

When you raise something with an exponent to another exponent, you can just multiply the exponents together to get:

$n^{\frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3}} = \left (\dfrac{1}{2^{3}} \right )^{\frac{2}{3}}$

or

$n = \left (\dfrac{1}{2^{3}} \right )^{\frac{2}{3}}$

or

$n = \dfrac{1^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(2^{3})^{\frac{2}{3}}}$

Now, $1$ raised to any power is just $1$, so the numerator is $1$.  With the denominator, we again multiply exponents to get:

$n = \dfrac{1}{2^{3 \cdot {\frac{2}{3}}}}$

or

$n = \dfrac{1}{2^{2}}$

or

$n = \dfrac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(4n)^\frac{3}{2} = (8)^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$

So we write as $4^{3/2} n^{3/2} = (2^{3})^{-1/3}$

Now writing as

$(2^{2})^{3/2} n^{3/2}= 2^{-1}$

we get as

$8n^{3/2}=1/2$

so $n^{3/2}=1/16$
Now squaring both sides we get

$n^{3}= (1/16) (1/16)$

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is: $\{4 n\}^\frac32 = \frac12$.(I think you understood this)

Now, write $4=2^2$ in the left side. Then the equation looks like

$(2^2)^\frac32 \times n^\frac32=\frac12$

$\Rightarrow $$n^\frac32 =$$\frac1{16}$

$\Rightarrow n=(\frac1{16})^\frac23$$=\frac14\times 2^{-\frac23}$